# Get list of files from az blob container, then grab all

Tags: azure, command-line-interface

Using the az cli within an azvm, I want to be able to list all the files within a specific container blob and then download those files. Let's say I have a container 'top' and then it has several subdirectories such as:

```
top/sub1/sub2/sub3/
```

Where in the folder sub3, there are multiple files. I would like to:

1. List all the files in sub3, and then
2. Retrieve all of the files in sub3 through the az cli.

I can only list the contents within 'top' with the command:

```
az storage container list --account-key ${key} --account-name top --query "[].{Name:name}" --output table
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`az storage container list` --> is used to list the containers inside a storage account.

Based on the shared information, we have understood that you are trying to list the blob under the subdirectories(sub1/sub2/sub3) inside a contianer `top` then you need to use `az storage blob directory list` cmdlet which is used to List blobs and blob subdirectories in a storage directory.

To test this  we have created a storage account with one container (top) and having multiple subdirectories(sub1/sub2/sub3) and we have used the below cmdlet to list the blob inside them.

```
az storage blob directory list -c top -d sub1/sub2/sub3 --account-name <storageAccountName> --query [].name -o table
```

**Here is the sample output for reference:**

[image]

Reference documentation for more information about [az storage blob directory list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/blob/directory?view=azure-cli-latest#az-storage-blob-directory-list) cmdlet.